# Reading and piping large files with C

Tags: c, file, file-io, postscript

I am interested in writing a utility that modifies PostScript files. It needs to traverse the file, make certain decisions about the page count and dimensions, and then write the output to a file or stdout making certain modifications to the PostScript code.

What would be a good way to handle file processing on a *NIX system in this case? I'm fairly new to pipes and forking in C, and it is my understanding that, in case of reading a file directly, I could probably seek back and forth around the input file, but if input is directly piped into the program, I can't simply rewind to the beginning of an input as the input could be a network stream for example, correct?

Rather than store the entire PS file into memory, which can grow huge, it seems like it would make more sense to buffer the input to disk while doing my first pass of page analysis, then re-read from the temporary file, produce output, and remove the temporary file. If that's a viable solution, where would be a good place to store such a file on a *NIX system? I'm not sure how safe such code would be either: the program could potentially be used by multiple users on the same server. It sounds like I would have make sure to save the file somewhere in a temporary directory unique to a given user account as well as give the temporary file on disk a fairly unique name.

Would appreciate any tips and pointers on this crazy puzzling world of file processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mkstemp(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp) to create your temporary file. It will handle concurrency issues for you. [`mmap(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) will let you move around in the file with abandon.

Comment: That's perfect! Although I do feel like I'm avoiding learning about temporary file creation concurrency a bit :)

Comment: What is the difference between `mkstemp` and `mktemp`?

Comment: @Helper: As given in the `mktemp(3)` man page, `mktemp()` has several security issues.

Answer (score 1):

*if input is directly piped into the program, I can't simply rewind to the beginning of an input as the input could be a network stream for example, correct?*

That's correct. You can only perform random access on a file.

If you read the file, perhaps you could build a table of metadata, which you can use to seek specific portions of the file later, without keeping the file itself in memory.

Answer (score 1):

/tmp is the temporary directory on unix systems.  It's specified by FHS.  It's cleaned out when the system is rebooted.

If you need more persistent data storage than that there's /var/tmp which is not cleaned out after reboots.  Also FHS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard